# How to bundle many forms in single instance in django

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

Main question is whether there is any method to bundle many django forms into single instance, to make clear what I need to explain my problem:

I have created bunch of form classes that need to work together to display a single view.

```
    from_form = move_forms.WaypointForm(prefix="marker-from", instance=move.from_place)
    to_form = move_forms.WaypointForm(prefix="marker-to", instance=move.to_place)
    #Notice that last two form are of the same class 
    through = ThroughFormset(prefix="through", queryset=move.waypoints_db.all())
    path_form = move_forms.CarMovePathForm(path=move.path)
    date_form = move_forms.MoveForm(instance=move)

    #put all this into context instance and render
```

All these forms basically display/edit the same instance of database --- but are reused throught the app in different configurations (so I cant just manually create class that will encapsulate it).

Having many forms in a webpage is a nuisance, for example I have to write code like that:

```
 if transportation_form.is_valid() and from_form.is_valid() and \
    to_form.is_valid() and through.is_valid() and path_form.is_valid():
```

I can't pass cleanly form property to views since most vievs use many forms in such manner.

Is there any sensible way to bundle these forms --- or is just my design broken (if so how to fix it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this

```
from_form = move_forms.WaypointForm(
    request.POST or None,
    prefix="marker-from",
    instance=move.from_place)
# ... other forms declared the same way

forms = {
    'from_form': from_form,
    'to_form':  to_form,
    # ...
}
if all(f.is_valid() for f in forms.values()):
    # ...
    return redirect('success')
return render(request, 'template.html', {'forms': forms})
```

Comment: Well I dislike passing dictionaries aroind (especially I would like to somehow enable passing that multi form as a view parameter). 

I might brew some `MultipleForm` class that will do something like you suggest, but I'm not that desperate yet --- and it is possible there is a ready solution.

Nevertheless this solution is definetely better than just using many variables.

Comment: @jb. How do you imagine a "ready solution"? Some class that bundles four forms and a formset with different kwargs? I don't think someone has created this.

Comment: Well some class that allows me to pass a list of forms to the constructir and provides methods and properties of forms that make sense to apply to all forms. Like errors :)